# Postgres SSL working fine with psql but not with jdbc

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc, psql

Postgres 14 is running on RHEL 9 with the below ssl related configs:

```
postgres=# SELECT name as "Parameter name", setting as value, short_desc FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%ssl%';
             Parameter name             |          value           |                         short_desc                         
----------------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 ssl                                    | on                       | Enables SSL connections.
 ssl_ca_file                            |                          | Location of the SSL certificate authority file.
 ssl_cert_file                          | server.crt               | Location of the SSL server certificate file.
 ssl_ciphers                            | HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL | Sets the list of allowed SSL ciphers.
 ssl_crl_dir                            |                          | Location of the SSL certificate revocation list directory.
 ssl_crl_file                           |                          | Location of the SSL certificate revocation list file.
 ssl_dh_params_file                     |                          | Location of the SSL DH parameters file.
 ssl_ecdh_curve                         | prime256v1               | Sets the curve to use for ECDH.
 ssl_key_file                           | server.key               | Location of the SSL server private key file.
 ssl_library                            | OpenSSL                  | Shows the name of the SSL library.
 ssl_max_protocol_version               |                          | Sets the maximum SSL/TLS protocol version to use.
 ssl_min_protocol_version               | TLSv1.2                  | Sets the minimum SSL/TLS protocol version to use.
 ssl_passphrase_command                 |                          | Command to obtain passphrases for SSL.
 ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload | off                      | Also use ssl_passphrase_command during server reload.
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers              | on                       | Give priority to server ciphersuite order.
(15 rows)
```

While connecting with psql, it works fine:

```
$ psql "sslmode=require host=<hostname> port=5301 dbname=postgres" -U postgres
psql (14.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.
```

But while connecting with jdbc, on client side it's showing:

```
SSL error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

and on Postgres server side we see:

```
LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: no suitable signature algorithm
```

Here is the sample Java code:
(`openjdk version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS`)

```
package com.ssl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {

private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:5301/postgres?ssl=true&sslmode=require";


private final String user = "postgres";
private final String password = "pswd";

/**
 *  * Connect to the PostgreSQL database
 *   *
 *    * @return a Connection object
 *     */
public Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    
try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    db.connect();

}
}
```

Tried changing the connection string to but no luck:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://<hostname>:5301/postgres?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory";
```

Just to add if I disable ssl i.e. set `sslmode=disable` it goes through fine. We are using wildcard certs and it appears to be working fine on other host of the same cluster on CentOS 7(`OpenSSL 1.1.1u+quic  30 May 2023`), somehow I feel this might be related to openssl version on RHEL 9(`OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023`).